# How to get heroku to run my scripts to launch the app

Tags: java, heroku, deployment

My app is built on a fullstack java MVC framework which does not need to deploy to a container. However I need to run a script to build and launch the app.

The content of the script is very simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f target/dist/start ]; then
    mvn clean package
    cd target/dist
    unzip *.zip
else
    cd target/dist
fi
./run $*
```

The script sit in the project home folder.

I've added the following command in `Procfile` but it doesn't work:

```
web: ./run_prod
```

When I deploy on heroku it says successful, but when I access my app it always says:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

The heroku log file shows:

```
2017-02-26T00:50:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-02-26T00:50:25.559742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=todobackend-act.herokuapp.com request_id=59af9898-b6c7-4a51-ae0e-33ffae0d1f6d fwd="61.69.245.214" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-26T00:50:26.533034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=todobackend-act.herokuapp.com request_id=bf30ce34-edb0-46dc-870c-b92a24bc0cf5 fwd="61.69.245.214" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-26T00:52:25.290301+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=todobackend-act.herokuapp.com request_id=0996409a-5024-4473-9616-1bc760c117e4 fwd="61.69.245.214" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-26T00:52:26.102216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=todobackend-act.herokuapp.com request_id=fd155207-cafc-420e-a0f1-0d3e6b73d4de fwd="61.69.245.214" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

It looks like your app was scaled down at some point (it's possible this happened automatically after a crash).

Comment: Actually I wonder if it is started at all. In order to start the app. I need to `cd target/dist && unzip *.zip && ./start`